# DNS server cache is empty

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-dns

while checking my DNS server, i found that there is no record in cache of my DNS server ( Please see the print-screen ), can you tell me why?

It is the only DNS server which is online, another DNS server is down. Even after 36 hours there is no cache entry showing in DNS Manager.

OS:- Window Server 2008 R2
[image]

Comment: Do you have recursion disabled on the server? Are DNS clients actually using this server for DNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some month back, i was unable to see any DNS record because, i mistakenly set the filter on, in Dns manager.
Just go to View menu in DNS manager and select --> Filter and select ALL names.

Answer (score 0):

please verify server root hints are configured or updated correctly.

Comment: This would be a much better answer, if you explain exactly how to do that. For instance, I know my way around BIND, but little of Windows DNS Manager.